# Miva Merchant - Emporium Plus Coupon Redemption BOGO feature NOT working

Tags: coupon, miva

Wondering if anyone out there has used Emporium Plus Coupon redemption module on a Miva Merchant store.
The BOGO feature refuses to work has anyone got it working???